# Depending on an external (a directory below) library

Tags: c++, cmake

I have this structure:

```
|- . (root)
|- CMakeLists.txt
|- LibraryA
---|- CMakeLists.txt
|- LibraryB
---|- CMakeLists.txt
|- Executable
---|- CMakeLists.txt
```

The `CMakeLists.txt` of the root just uses `add_subdirectory`.

I wonder, how can I make `LibraryA` to use `LibraryB` as an external library? And `Executable` to use both libraries also as an external library? (Of course, without add directories like "../". I want to be able to select the directory on cmake if it's not found automatically - this way I can put the libraries in other directories and don't be concerned about where they are - this way I can put each one in a git repository and make them independent). Any ideas?

**@edit**

And also how to have the include directory of that external library.

Comment: Do you mean "rootCMake" adds both "LibA" and "LibB" currently?  Can you add some of the CMakeLists.txt to clarify your question?

Comment: No, `LibraryA` and `LibraryB` are independent and `LibraryA` depends on `LibraryB`. I want to add `LibraryB` as an external library independent of the directory. CMake will try to find the `LibraryB` but if it doesn't find, I can specify the directory.

Comment: The easiest way to control the library/requirements/locations is to create a package: [doc](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-packages.7.html) and [example](https://github.com/forexample/package-example)